# Make an Anonymous object for Linq Select statement

Tags: c#, linq

I get an Array of strings that has names of properties in it. I want to only load these properties when getting data, in this case from a DB trough Entity Framework. Something like:

```
var result = db.myTable
               .Where(x => x.Id == ”someValue”)
               .Select(y => new {y.someProperty, y.someOtherproperty, ...});
```

How do I create the Anonymous object from the string array. I would like to have something like:

```
var MyObj = new {};
foreach(var I in MyStrinArr)
{
   ... Add the properties here ...
}
var result = db.myTable.Where(x => x.Id==”someValue”).Select(y => obj);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not (directly) possible, because anonymous classes are *generated* at compile-time. Iterating over a string array is at runtime. So this isn't comparable.

---

There are possibilities with dynamic linq, you should read the ScottGu's Blog
 on this: [dynamic-linq](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library) It is using techniques creating types with properties at runtime. Download the dynamiclinqcsharp file and check the source. There is a `ClassFactory` within the DynamicLibrary.cs, which allows you to create types. `public Type GetDynamicClass(IEnumerable<DynamicProperty> properties)`

Answer (score 0):

solution with IQueryable.Select extensions [(github)](https://github.com/mustaddon/LinqString?tab=readme-ov-file#linqstring-):

```
using LinqString; // nuget

var result = db.myTable
  .Where(x => x.Id == "someValue")
  .Select("someProperty", "someOtherProperty")
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**